# Inheritance involving inner classes C++

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am very new to the concept of inheritance and therefore I have a question. Imagine that I have a class like this:

```
class A{
  protected:
    class B{
      int x;
      B() : x(3){}
      int g(int y) {return x*y;}
      friend class A;
    };
    B *b;
  public:
    int f(int y) {return b->g(y);}
};
```

I want to inherit class A, not overwrite method f, but overwrite method g which is being called by f, so that f would work differently in the derived class. How could I do that?

Comment: You can _'overwrite'_ (virtual) methods only in derivates of the inner `class B`, not directly in derivates of `class A`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to specify the constructor(s) and mandatory in this case copy operator for class A. Let's assume that one of your constructors looks like this:

```
A::A()
{
    b = new B;
}
```

Then what you need to do is to replace b with a pointer to a class derived from B in the constructor(s) of the class derived from A:

```
class C : public A
{
protected:
    class D : public B
    {
        int z;
    public:
        D() : z(27) { }
        int g(int y) { return z + y;}
    };

public:
    C()
    {
        // Delete pointer to B created by the parent class constructor that 
        // executes just before this constructor.
        delete b;
        // Point b to an instance of D; possible because D is derived from B.
        b = new D;
    }
};
```

Just remember that with manipulations like that you need to implement all constructors and copy operator and the destructor.